# Cruisecontrol not seeing a failed batch job

Tags: .net, tfs, cruisecontrol

I am trying to setup cruisecontrol to call a series of batch jobs, one calling the other sequentially.

One batch script calls the other by the below syntax:

```
 call nextbat %1
```

Problem is that I noticed that even if the call fails due to the next batch script not found, Cruisecontrol exits with a success.
here is the exit log:

```
<buildresults>
  <message level="Error">'nextbat' is not recognized as an internal or external     command,</message>
  <message level="Error">operable program or batch file.</message>
</buildresults>
```

The last line of my bat file is already

```
exit /b %errorlevel%
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Should we guess your batch script?

Comment: KMoraz, the contents of the batch job should not matter. As I mentioned above, my batch script A, simply tries to execute the script B by 'call B %1'. If script B.bat is not found on that location, then I was expecting Cruisecontrol to show a failure. Infact Cruisecontrol correctly shows the above mentioned Error message, but still exists with a Success code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.

I had to change

```
<successExitCodes>-1,0,1</successExitCodes>
```

to

```
<successExitCodes>-1,0</successExitCodes>
```

under

```
<Tasks><exec>
```